# Different environment variables per pod in a deployment plan?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Would it be possible to create such a deployment that can create let's say half of the pods with some environment variables and the rest with different environment variables. If possible, is this approach assumed to be best practice?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a blue/green approach?

Comment: Sounds like a very good point. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you would just want two deployments and a service for each deployment... You can expose each service through a route or ingress.

Comment: You can also have one service for both deployments, it's just a matter of setting the same labels for Service selector. By using Istio you can manage the traffic in more precise way ( https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/  https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/traffic-shifting/ )

Comment: And if you can control container image build process - you can create an Entrypoint script that export a set of env variables based on randomly generated 0 or 1 before starting the container application. ( https://www.redpill-linpro.com/sysadvent/2016/12/13/bash_random_numbers.html ) You can also mount the scipt from a configMap and call it from Pod's command.

Answer (score 0):

Like Christ Bolton suggested in comments, dividing single deployment into multiple set of deployments and services would be the simplest solution. In each deployment You can have different [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables).

Hope it helps.